# Ruby chat bot command cooldown

Tags: ruby, bots, discord

I'm writing a bot for a discord server using the discordrb gem in Ruby. How could I prevent the bot (and users) from spamming commands in the chat channels? I was thinking about putting certain commands on a 5 minute cooldown, but the only way I could come up with is by using `sleep` but that prevents the bot from accepting other commands during that time.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your code looks like but you could do something like this:

Initialize `@last_reply_time` with some old time value, then before each response:

```
if Time.now >= @last_reply_time + 300  #(seconds)
  # Reply
  # ...
  @last_reply_time = Time.now # update the @last_reply_time last
end
```

Obviously you can extend this to check multiple variables, or a list of times for each type of reply and make the logic more complex.